# Display structured message when user clicks "New Conversation"

Tags: smooch

Our team is stuck on what should be very simple functionality with smooch / sunshine conversations. We are looking to provide our users with a "multi choice" selection whenever they click "New conversation", think:

---

Hi, how can we help you today?
**[Technical Support] [Sales] [Other]**

---

From there, allow the user to click one of those options and continue with a normal conversation flow. I'm surprised this isn't documented or discussed more, can anybody help point us in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [pre-chat capture](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/web-messenger/#prechat-capture) is designed as a once/user and not a once/conversation feature, and there's no OOTB/built-in delegate/etc. to capture clicks of the `New Conversation` button.

If you can capture this click event or override the button, you can achieve the result you describe by:

- [frontend] calling [createConversation()](https://github.com/zendesk/sunshine-conversations-web#createconversationoptions) (MAU charged at this point)
- [backend] catching the `conversation:created` event via a [subscribed webhook](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#webhooks)
- [backend] respond using a series of [quick-reply buttons](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/structured-messages/#reply-buttons) or a [form message](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/web-messenger/#forms).